# Multiple internal IPs on a GCE instance

Tags: centos, linux-networking, centos7, google-compute-engine

In order to solve a unique problem in our org I would like to create one or more instances that are assigned multiple internal IP addresses. However I haven't been able to find anything in the UI, docs, or API regarding adding additional internal IPs, and manually assigning an IP from within the instance itself does not result in a functional address.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What did google support say about this?

Comment: Well the GCE tag is supposedly monitored by them, so we'll see. `:I`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set multiple internal static IP addresses for your VM using Google Compute Engine routes. For the steps visit [this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#set_a_static_target_ip_address).